# How to convert this query to SQL Server 2000 syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am running this query to SQL Server 2008+ but it doesn't work on SQL Server 2000. 
and i need this to execute.

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT
        custnum,
        custname,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY custnum, custname ORDER BY custnum )
    FROM
        cust
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What means `but it doesn't work`? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you running SQL Server 2000? It's woefully outdated, unsupported and very insecure software now.

Comment: @Jens The OP posted a CTE (Common Table Expression) with a PARTITION statement, these are recent additions to T-SQL and would require a radical rewrite (possibly using `CURSOR`) to work in older versions of SQL Server.

Comment: sql 2000 don.t have `Row_number()`  or `CTE` etc. p.s i am only dealing with clients db and that's why.

Comment: yes @dai and i want to know how am i going to do that and also the codes  ofcourse. thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, your sample query shows that you have different `custname` on each `custnum`. That smells like bad design IMO.

Comment: yes i am aware of it. my client's db admin left things like "same id with different customer name" etc. and that's why i'm trying to fix it. by delete all items with same id and same name

Comment: This might help: http://archive.cpradio.org/work/row_number-and-partition-by-in-sql-server-2000/

Comment: im dealing with 10k+ records here

Comment: @Daviddelacruz, then state that in your question. There are other solutions aside from using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY..)`.

Comment: my fix would be `WITH CTE AS(SELECT custnum, custname,RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY custnum,custname ORDER BY custnum) FROM cust) delete from CTE where RN > 1`  but it will only work on sql2005+ :(
@FelixPamittan thanks i'll read it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to SQL Server 2005, this problem domain was solved with ordered inserts into a `#temp` table with an `IDENTITY` column to generate the sequence number. This would solve `RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` requirements.

E.g.:

```
    -- Create empty temp table
    SELECT custnum, custname, IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) as RN
    INTO #cust
    FROM cust
    WHERE 0 = 1

    -- Populate with ORDER BY, to generate ascending RN
    INSERT INTO #cust
        (custnum, custname)
    SELECT
        custnum, custname
    FROM 
        cust
    ORDER BY
        custnum, custname
```

At that point, you can query `MIN()` for each custnum/custname grouping and use that as you'd use the CTE.

However ... is `ROW_NUMBER()` really what you want here ? Seems like you'd want `RANK()`, not `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
select custnum,custname from
(
select (select count(*) from cust as t1 where t1.custnum<=t2.custnum) as sno,
 custnum,custname from cust as t2
) as t
where sno>1
```